# Uncaught TypeError: Object has no method 'sortContents'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i am new to javascript. i have written a small code. but it is showing the above mentioned error in console. i don't know why. any help would be appreciated.
thanks in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>My First JavaScript</h1>
<p>Click the button to display the date.</p>
<p id="demo"></p>

<button type="button" onclick="testing()">Try it</button>

<script>
function testing(){
    alert("testing");
    var x = responseAjax;
    x.resultType = "albums";
    x.result = "hell owrld";
    x.destId = "songsBody1";
    x.sortContents();
}
function responseAjax(){
    this.sortContents = function(){
    alert("this issor contentes"); alert(this.resultType); alert(this.result); alert(this.destId); 
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do `var x = new responseAjax;` `var x = responseAjax;` will give you just the function reference but you want to create an object instead.

Comment: thank you. i have forgot to add "new" keyword.

Answer (score 3):

Make the instance as

```
var x = new responseAjax();
```